# Рассылки php

Tags: php, mysql

Уважаемые, как организовать рассылку. Не по мыльникам, а по своим участникам, то есть у меня примерно 100 тысяч человек на сайте и каждому отправить такое сообщение, очень накладно для БД. Быть может кто по мудрее, подскажет, как лучше это реализовать. чтобы не добавлять 100 тысяч строк. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выводите юзверей в массив -> запускаем цикл перебора наших юзверей -> инсертим мессагу в нашу коллонку, где user_id = for_id.

Comment: "у меня примерно 100 тысяч человек на сайте" Быть может есть какая то идея, чтобы не добавлять 100 тысяч строк в таблицу сообщений...Мне предлагали добавить всего 1 строку, но чтобы она выводилась у всех, так вот. Если юзер захочет удалить сообщение то как быть с этой одной строкой.

Comment: вводите таблицу "общих сообщений" в нее вносите сообщение, а у юзеров, храните id и статус сообщения - прочитано, удалено.

Answer (score 1):

надо запилить сайт junior.hashcode.ru ))

1. запрос к бд, выбираешь все нужные емайлы
2. в цикле их перебираешь, цикл в свою очередь отправляет емайлы, подставляя поочередно нужный

Comment: А так же сайт внимательного чтения))

> не по мыльникам, а по своим участникам

То есть внутренняя рассылка, а не на почтовики. Как я понимаю автор добавляет сообщения в таблицу сообщений БД каждому участнику.